# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. Please help this non technical background person

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, catch-block

I have node and npm, and I don't have an idea of how to fix this problem.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

can someone please explain to me what it means by '**throwing** inside of a **async function** without a **catch** block' means?

along with a specific details on how to resolve the error?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add some code block so that it's better to understand what actually is causing this error?

Comment: you have a promise, it is rejecting, your code doesn't handle it, this warning appears ... solution, handle the promise rejection - inside an `async function`, you would do something like `try { await promise; } catch(e) { handle the error e }` to handle the rejection